# Make sure users only access THEIR records in REST API

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, saas, json-api

I am currently building a rest api on node.js and express.js for my next web application. I am building a multi-tenant SAAS app, and I'm just wondering the best or "most acceptable" way according to REST API standards (if any such thing exists yet) to make it so that if a user makes an api call to say:

/api/users

That is NOT pulling every single user in the database (mongodb), but just that particular users company members.

I could just make a call to: api/users/?companyId=1, but I can't help but think there has to be a better way. Maybe passing the company id with EVERY api call as a header of some sort?

Any ideas for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique identifying name or 'code' for each company, you could have a multi-tenant api with the company code as the base of the url:

https://companycode.myapi.com/v1/users

You could also extend that for different environments:

https://companycode.staging.myapi.com/v1/users

Answer (score 0):

you can force your users to authenticate and associate their account with a company. through the middleware in the request pipeline you'll give the request object access to their user account once they've logged in, which you can use to filter the query results.

```
api.get('/v1/users', function(req, res) { 
  console.log(req.user); 
  //create a service that gets users for user(companyUser) 
  //mongooseModel.find({}).where(req.user._id.toString()
}
```